# is it possible to access user credential from a LDAP server while writing jmeter login sampler test

Tags: ldap, jmeter

I want to test a login page from jmeter sampler.
My requirement is to extract username and password from a LDAP server and use them in jmeter  http request sampler as parameter.
I am able to extract credential from csv file but not sure how to do it from a LDAP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although JMeter comes with [LDAP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ldap-test-plan.html) samplersMost likely you won't be able to get the password from LDAP server. If you do - the password will not be in plain text and it cannot be quickly decoded.

If your LDAP implementation is [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/) you could get username/password combinations from underlying Berkeley DB using [JDBC Driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/db-faq-095848.html#DoesBerkeleyDBsupportJDBC) and [JMeter's JDBC Request](https://blazemeter.com/blog/secret-building-database-test-plan-with-jmeter) Sampler

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for useful response.I am using open LDAP but with LDIF as backend.is there any support in jmeter to acces LDIF?

Comment: LDIF files and associated LDAP commands i.e. `ldapsearch` can be [invoked from JMeter locally or remotely](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) but I believe you won't be able to get the password this way as well.